# 3rd Person RigidBody Movement Script Using CineMachine

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, rigid-bodies, cinemachine

I am trying to create a 3rd person movement script using Cinemachine as camera, I followed Brackeys "THIRD PERSON MOVEMENT in Unity" YouTube tutorial. I then Changed the base of it from character controller to rigidbody and the movement works perfectly fine. However my code sets the velocity of the rigidbody's y axis to 0 when I move the player which fights the gravity making the player jitter slowly to the ground when I move. The Character however does drop to the ground when the player stops moving. All I need is for the script to ignore the y axis and simply listen to unity's gravity.

```
    void Update()
{
    if (!photonView.isMine)
    {
        Destroy(GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().gameObject);
        Destroy(GetComponentInChildren<Cinemachine.CinemachineFreeLook>().gameObject);
        return;
    }

    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 1, transform.position.z), 0.01f, layerMask);

    Vector3 inputVector = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

    if (inputVector.magnitude >= 0.1f)
    {
        float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(inputVector.x, inputVector.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
        float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

        Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;

        rb.velocity = moveDir.normalized * speed;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The player jitters because, in your movement section, you set the y velocity to 0, since `Vector3.forward` returns `new Vector3(0, 0, 1)` and you only rotate the vector around the y axis. Instead of this, consider doing:

```
Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(transform.forward.x, rb.velocity.y, transform.forward.z);
```

This will preserve the velocity as it was, removing the jittering.

Note: `transform.forward` automatically gets the forward vector for the player.